# Refresh each excel file separately to remove {} wrapping around equations

Tags: excel

We are using Excel for Mac v16.60. Here is a screenshot showcasing our issue. The equation is for cell P81 which we are clicked on. Note the `{` `}` at the start and end of equation in formula bar.

[image]

For all of these problematic when we click on the formula far, the `{` and `}` magically vanish:

[image]

and after doing **nothing but (i) clicking on the formula bar, and (ii) hitting enter**, the cell is fixed.

[image]

There are ~1000 cells in this spreadsheet throwing the same error that can all be fixed by simply clicking the cell, clicking the formula bar, and clicking enter. However, the refresh all button in the Data tab is useless and is not refreshing / fixing the cells.

[image]

I also tried to search & replace `{` and `}` for empty strings but it did not work.

I believe this issue is happening because of an earlier issue with the excel file (the file was lost & then "recovered" somehow, and these errors have been here ever since recovering the file). How can we fix our spreadsheet without manually clicking through 1000 cells?

Comment: Those brackets (`{}`) usually indicate it is an [array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) removing them may cause other problems with the functionality of your file. What is the error your are talking about?

Comment: it is saying `Invalid Name Error`. However, I'm not quite sure what the error actually is given that the error message vanishes once I click on a cell, click on a formula bar, and hit enter to refresh the cell...

Comment: the function in the cell, which can be seen in the screenshots, is an Index-Match

Comment: It looks like you have a `concat` UDF that is not working.